# How can I specify to execute a test as JUnit and not TestNg from command line?

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, command-line, junit

I am trying to execute an appium test from command line and always getting the same error. 
The same test works OK when executing it from Intellij. My guess is that for some reason, the test is being treated as testNG test and not as JUnit. I got the same response when first executed the test from Intellij as testNg by mistake. 
Therefore, the question would be... Is there a way to specify from command line to execute the test as JUnit and not testNg? 
This is the command I am using.

> mvn -Dtest=AddActivitySuite test

This is part of the result:

```
-------------------------------------------------------  T E S T S
------------------------------------------------------- Running cga.testobjects.AddActivitySuite org.testng.TestNGException:  Failure in JUnit mode for class cga.testobjects.AddActivitySuite: could not create/run JUnit test suite:  Cannot find JUnit method class junit.framework.TestSuite$1.warning  at org.testng.junit.JUnitTestRunner.runFailed(JUnitTestRunner.java:237)     at org.testng.junit.JUnitTestRunner.start(JUnitTestRunner.java:230)     at org.testng.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:211)   at org.testng.TestRunner$1.run(TestRunner.java:667)     at org.testng.TestRunner.runWorkers(TestRunner.java:1178)   at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRunJUnit(TestRunner.java:698)   at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:605)   at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)  at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)     at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)     at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)  at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1158)    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1083)     at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:999)   at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:132)     at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeSingleClass(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:112)  at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:99)  at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:147)  at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)     at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)  at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121) Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.588 sec - in cga.testobjects.AddActivitySuite

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 4.611 s [INFO] Finished at: 2016-04-19T23:55:20-03:00 [INFO] Final Memory: 13M/224M [INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project Automation: No tests were executed!  (Set
-DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1] [ERROR]  [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

- OSX10.10.5.
- Test and classes on Java.

Comment: Is JUnit on your class path? testNG will run JUnit tests as JUnit. looking at the error you are getting either junit is not on your classpath or you have the wrong version.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I checked and JUnit is in my class path and junit version is 4.12.

Comment: Do you have any TestNG tests in your?

Comment: Yes. I do. I tried from intellij and it runs successfully. But I had to manually select to execute it as JUnit. When it was executed as testNg, I got similar failures.